# Windows Server 2012 - What type of memory do I have?

Tags: windows-server-2012, memory

My Windows Server is running on 3gb of memory right now, and I would like to upgrade to 16gb.

However, I don't know what type of memory to buy.  I know that the notches in the physical RAM are different depending on the memory type.

Is there a way in Windows Server 2012 to detect the type of memory so I get the correct one?

Comment: If you know what server make/model number you are running on, yes. From just 2012 itself, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way that Windows can guess what RAM is supported.
You need to consult the hardware documentation of your server for that

Comment: Usually the manufacturer has an approved part list as well you can lookup once you know the model number of the server to see what's official supported.